# Journal Header and Footer

Tags: header-footer, templates, journal-publishing

I am using standart article document and I want to form a template as in the shown figure. How can I do it? Thank you.

*Edit.* I have formed the following but here the title page appears on the second new page.
I would be also very glad if you can help me replacing `\hspace{-6.5mm}` with a better alternative.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\AtBeginDocument{{\noindent\small Journal Name\\
Vol. \textbf{X} (year), No. X, pp. XXX--XXX.}}

\AtEndDocument{{\noindent\small Author 1: Address 1.\\
E-mail: author1@.xxx.yyy\\
Author 2: Address 2.\\
E-mail: author2@.xxx.yyy}}

\title{Article Title}
\author{Author 1 and Author 2}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\blfootnote{\hspace{-6.5mm}Received Date 1 and in revised form Date 2.\\
AMS Subject Classification: Cls 1, Cls 2.\\
Key words and phrases: Keyword 1, keyword 2.}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\textellipsis
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
\textellipsis

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you writing a manuscript for a specific journal? Maybe there is a template that already does the layout for you.

Comment: Oh no, I want to learn how to do it for personal curiosity.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far, in terms of LaTeX code. Please also indicate how important it is that some parts of the title page use a serif font whereas others use a sans-serif font. And, how big should the page block be? The less guesswork you impose, the more likely you'll get a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Just normal font is enough. I have tried to see how some other journals modify amsar.cls but I do not want anything complicated. May be it can be even done with fancy header. But I could not make it work myself.

Comment: This site is not a good place for "do this for me" type programming requests. Unless you're willing to show some effort yourself, you may not be getting a lot of answers.

Comment: Thank you Mico, it is not the first time I am using this web site and I know how things work here. But I am trying to get some information and comments for what I want to do. I would be very glad if you can tell me possible package names in this direction. Thank you.

Comment: One comment: use `No.\ X, pp.\ ` because the dot is not full stop.

Comment: The ideal would be to crate a page style for the first page to put the box on the header. So you wouldn't need the negative space.

Comment: @Sigur: How can I set a style for the first page? Can you show me some directions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ps@titlepage}{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \def\@oddhead{\vbox to\z@{\kern-\topmargin\kern-.5in
      \hbox{\begin{tabular}{l}
          Journal Name\\
          Vol.~\textbf{X} (year), No.~X, pp.~XXX--XXX.
        \end{tabular}\hfil}\vss}}%
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead%
  \def\@oddfoot{}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\newcommand{\AMSclass}[1]{\gdef\@AMSclass{#1}}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\gdef\@keywords{#1}}
\def\@AMSclass{}
\def\@keywords{}

\let\ori@maketitle\maketitle
\def\maketitle{\ori@maketitle\thispagestyle{titlepage}}

\let\ori@endabstract\endabstract
\def\endabstract{\par\bigskip%
  \ifx\@AMSclass\empty\else
    \textit{AMS classification:} \@AMSclass.\par
  \fi
  \ifx\@keywords\empty\else
    \textit{Keywords and phrases:} \@keywords.\par
  \fi
  \ori@endabstract}
\makeatother


\title{Article Title\thanks{%
    Received Date 1 and in revised form Date 2.}}

\author{Author 1 and Author 2}
\date{\today}

\AMSclass{Cls 1, Cls 2}
\keywords{Keyword 1, keyword 2}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  \textellipsis
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very educating sample, thank you. I could adopt it for my purpose.